# What is so special with port 80?

Tags: port

I've been doing some configuration, including releasing some ports, designating them to applications. I've seen so many applications want port 80. Can I ask what is so special with it? Why not port 90? 70?

Answer (score 3):

Port 80 is the standard for [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)#Common_port_numbers) which is the major networking protocol.

So if you have an URL like this (without any port number):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242839/what-is-so-special-with-port-80/31242897#31242897
```

your browser will communicate with the webserver over port 80.

Answer (score 2):

As @Glorfindel stated, port 80 is the standard for HTTP.

To elaborate - there are a number of fixed TCP, UDP ports "reserved" for different services from 1 - 1024. best practice is to use a port number larger than 1024 for non-standard traffic.

For instance, you might want both an IIS server and a tomcat server running on the same machine. you could issue 80 to one, and 8080 to another, or 8080 to one, and 8090 to another. (note that J2EE servers such as Tomcat, Glassfish, Weblogic, etc often default to 8080, which also defines as HTTP_alternate)

Also, in some operating systems, you need elevated privileges (administrator/root) to register a port below 1024, therefore you may want to use port 8080 in place of 80, for ease of use.

A further reading suggestion:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Note also that (historically at least) Skype, for instance used port 80 to listen on, since it open in many routers, etc.